# Создание списка часов в сутках с шагом 15 минут

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

Необходимо сформировать список часов в сутках с шагом 15 минут. Вот такой:

```
time = ['00:00', '00:15', '00:30', '00:45', '01:00', '01:15', ...,'24:00']
```

Подскажите, как можно упростить или улучшить решение:

```
time = []
for hour in range(25):
    if hour < 10:
        hour = "0{}".format(hour)
    for min in range(0,60,15):
        if min == 0:
            min = "00"
        string = "{}:{}".format(str(hour), str(min))
        if string == "24:15":
            break
        time.append("{}:{}".format(str(hour), str(min)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Вариант с использованием модуля `datetime`:**

```
from datetime import datetime as DT, time, date, timedelta  

res = [(DT.combine(date.today(), time(0,0)) + timedelta(minutes=i)).time().strftime("%H:%M") 
       for i in range(0, 24*60, 15)]
```

---

**Вариант с использованием модуля `itertools`:** - находим декартово произведение компонент часов и минут:

```
from itertools import product

res = [f"{h:02d}:{m:02d}" for h,m in product(range(24), range(0, 60, 15))]
```

---

**Результат для обоих вариантов:**

```
In [28]: print(res)
['00:00', '00:15', '00:30', '00:45', '01:00', '01:15', '01:30', '01:45', '02:00', '02:15', '02:30', '02:45', '03:00', '03:15', '03:30', '03:45', '04:00', '04:15', '04:30', '04:45', '05:00', '05:15', '05:30', '05:45', '06:00', '06:15', '06:30', '06:45', '07:00', '07:15', '07:30', '07:45', '08:00', '08:15', '08:30', '08:45', '09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00', '11:15', '11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '12:30', '12:45', '13:00', '13:15', '13:30', '13:45', '14:00', '14:15', '14:30', '14:45', '15:00', '15:15', '15:30', '15:45', '16:00', '16:15', '16:30', '16:45', '17:00', '17:15', '17:30', '17:45', '18:00', '18:15', '18:30', '18:45', '19:00', '19:15', '19:30', '19:45', '20:00', '20:15', '20:30', '20:45', '21:00', '21:15', '21:30', '21:45', '22:00', '22:15', '22:30', '22:45', '23:00', '23:15', '23:30', '23:45']
```

---

> PS как правильно заметил @iksuy, времени `24:00` не существует. Через
>   минуту после `23:59` будет `00:00`.
>
> ---

**UPDATE:**

> "по поводу 24:00 поясню, в списке данное значение таки необходимо для
>   обозначения временного диапазона"

```
res += ["24:00"]
```

или:

```
res.append("24:00")
```

Comment: Спасибо за варианты решения  
по поводу `24:00` поясню, в списке данное значение таки необходимо для обозначения временного диапазона "полные сутки" в скрипте

Answer (score 3):

`format` можно использовать более полезно в данном случае, и цикл до 25 вам не нужен, ведь времени 24:00 нету:

```
time = []
for hour in range(24):
    for min in range(0,60,15):
        time.append("{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hour, min))
```

Comment: `"времени 24:00 нету"` ++ :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот это

```
for min in range(0,60,15):
    if min == 0:
        min = "00"
```

можно сократить до

```
for min in ["00", "15", "30", "45"]:
```

И для часов брать range(24), тогда и

```
if string == "24:15":
    break
```

не понадобится. Если в конце списка нужно еще "24:00", то просто добавить отдельно.